# Coordinates of dimension-wise maximum of Matlab array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have 5-dimensional array of numbers. The goal is to find maximum values along 5-th dimension and their coordinates. I use

```
[x,y] = max(A,[],5);
```

Ideally I expect that `x == A(y)`, however this does not appear to happen. I need an idea of how to translate `y` to an array of coordinates `z` such that `x == A(z)`. Using find + loops is costly in my case, since matrices are huge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your matrix `A` has dimension of `(m,n,o)`. Now you have the indices of maximum entries along the `3rd` dimension in `y` and the corresponding maximum values in `x`. You can access the maximum values by the following code-

```
z = (1:m*n)' + (y(:)-1)*(m*n); % linear index of these locations in full array
final_matrix = reshape(A(z),m,n);
```

It can be easily extended to 5 dimensional matrices.

Try this code for 5-dimensional-

```
[x,y] = max(A,[], 5);
z = (1:m*n*o*p)' + (y(:)-1)*(m*n*o*p); 
final_matrix = reshape(A(z),m,n,o,p);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = size(A);
[v,ii] = max(reshape(A,[],s(3)));
[i1 j1 ] = ind2sub(s(1:2),ii);
out = [v;i1;j1;1:s(3)]';
```